# Hi-volume Email SP with SF Integration

Tags: email

Our solution requires us to send out emails well beyond the 1K daily limit and possibly attachments.  Up to 10K a day is possible for peak periods.

I am now looking at Email Service Providers for a solution.  The solution needs us to allow us to be called via an API, as we need to check business rules before executing each mail, also receive bounced results which we can capture and update contact record.

This could easily be done in SF if it wasn't for the 1K limit.

Any guidance will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is much you can do on the platform when it comes to email limits. I believe 1k is the limit of email from apex, however if you send by a workflow I reckon the email would be a bit higher. If that still doesn't work for you then best option will be to look into a 3rd party provider for sending emails, something like [MassMailer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005uxj5EAA) or [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) etc.

Comment: We decided to go with SendGrid. It has an assortment of API's which will serve our needs.

Answer (score 0):

This blog piece by Jeff Douglas on how to build a bulk emailer with google app engine might help: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/25/build-a-bulk-emailer-for-salesforce-with-app-engine/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the integration between Salesforce and the [Salesforce Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget](http://www.exacttarget.com/products/email-marketing)).  I would recommend talking with your account rep from Salesforce.